# Python Scrapy Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, django, segmentation-fault, scrapy, nltk

I have a django project where I use nltk. I get segmentation error while trying to

```
import nltk
```

I found the exact line where it happens and it's collocations.py:38.
I also found out that I get this error only in django unit-tests and django manage.py shell(actually shell_plus, but I don't thing it changes something), but not in custom management commands (which maybe means, that I won't get this error in production)

I use django django 1.4.5, nltk 2.0.4, python 2.7.3.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Update of python to 2.7.4 hasn't effected

**UPDATE:** Update of numpy to 1.7.1 and scipy to 0.12.0 hasn't effected

**UPDATE:** I found the statement, which causes the segfault (I suppose, as much as I moved it from module scope to function scope, which caused segfault not to happen)

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
```

It's the class from crawling `scrapy` framework, which I used in custom module for executing scrapy spider as a python script. It seems like segfault is not NLTK fault, but scrapy. Probably somehow this class rewrote some data of nltk, that's why it's segfaulted.

Comment: [collocations.py:38](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/master/nltk/collocations.py#L38) is `from nltk.util import ingrams`. [`nltk.util`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/master/nltk/util.py) doesn't import anything that seems likely to cause a segfault; following the import tree down, it seems to all be from the stdlib. Are you sure that's the right line?

Comment: @Dougal thank you for your attention! I found out, that it's not NLTK, which is segfaulted, but scrapy

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with CrawlerProcess. Scrapy had failed to install libxml2. Try entering this into the command prompt:

```
easy_install lxml
pip install scrapy --upgrade
```

My program executed correctly after this.